# How to use brand name with Apostrophe

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table called "Shops" and I would like to  filter this on column name "Shopname" with only field values - 'Romford' and 'St.John's Road'.How do I write where clause as one of the cities names contains Apostrophe. 
Help please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your single quote, by "doubling" it up. Thus:

```
WHERE Shopname = 'St.John''s Road'
```

If, however, the value is coming from an application then you will have properly parametrised your query, and variable values don't need to be escaped. Thus a variable `@ShopName` with the value "St.John's Road" will work fine below:

```
WHERE ShopName = @ShopName
```

Comment: If from app code and the query isn't already parameterized, changing it to a parameterized query will fix this problem and provide other benefits, including better security, eliminate the need to enclose literals (or not) depending on the type, eliminate the need to escape quotes within strings, avoid the need to format date string literals in a particular way, do not require decimal separators, improve performance by promoting execution plan cache reuse, and result in cleaner code that's easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double up single quotes in a string.  So you would write:

```
where shopname = 'St. John''s Road'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [escape it as shown below](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/17/sql-server-how-to-escape-single-quotes-fix-error-105-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/):

```
select 'St. John''s Road' as Shopname
```